# The proteins "eluted" or "were eluted"?

Tags: purification, terminology, chromatography

In describing proteins, I've written "the proteins detached from the [Ni-IDA] matrix and **were eluted** from the column"

Should I use "were" or can something simply "elute" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **eˈlute**, *v.*
>
> *trans.* To wash out, cleanse. Now spec.  [after German eluieren, in same sense] to wash (adsorbed matter) away from the substance that has adsorbed it.

It's transitive, so you elute something, rather than something eluting. Your original "were eluted" is correct.

Comment: God sorry I didn't even think of checking transitive/intransitive :| Not quite with it today, cheers Aesin